# How much feature implementation control do admins have?

Tags: discussion

Exactly how much control do admins here have when it comes to implementing a new feature that's not on every stack exchange site?

Comment: IMO I think the title is too long and the body is too short.

Comment: @Beta is it better now?

Comment: That's much better ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by "admins"?

If you mean SE employees, well, nobody can really know for sure. However, it's very unlikely that an entirely new, unique feature would be implemented just for a single site. (There have been exceptions, though: chess rendering engine for Chess.SE, Balsamiq Mockups integration for UX.SE, etc. Note that these are usually just extra things that users can include in questions and answers, ex. MathJax, Stack Snippets, etc.)

If you mean us diamond moderators, nothing. We have no connection whatsoever to Stack Exchange inc. the company, and the only thing we can really do to influence the company itself that normal users don't have access to is pinging SE employees in chat.

Comment: Yea thanks, I meant diamond mods :D